requiredDeploymentEnvironments is not getting selected using graphql
I am trying to enable the below in the branch protection.

query
curl -X POST   -H "Authorization: Bearer <PAT>"   -H "Content-Type: application/json"   -d '{
    "query": "mutation { createBranchProtectionRule(input: { repositoryId: \"REPO_ID\", pattern: \"release/*\", requiresApprovingReviews: true,  requiresCodeOwnerReviews: true, requiredApprovingReviewCount: 1 , requireLastPushApproval: true,  requiresConversationResolution: true,  dismissesStaleReviews: true ,  requiresStrictStatusChecks: true , requiresStatusChecks: true ,restrictsPushes : true , requiredDeploymentEnvironments: [\"dev\"]}) { branchProtectionRule { id } } }"
    }' https://api.github.com/graphql

output :
{"data":{"createBranchProtectionRule":{"branchProtectionRule":{"id":"BPR_kwDOMI-6g84DL5Qd"}}}}

However it is not getting selected in the protection rule.


Mutation createBranchProtectionRule  needs an input
requiresDeployments: true

in order to enforce deployments.
This mutation creates a BPR with "Require deployments to succeed before merging" checked and environment dev selected:
mutation { 
  createBranchProtectionRule(input: { 
  repositoryId: "REPO_ID", 
  pattern: "release/*", 
  requiresDeployments: true, 
  requiredDeploymentEnvironments: ["dev"]
  }) 
  { 
    branchProtectionRule { id } 
  }
} 

